# Ubuntu 16.04 installer is not creating partition in Dell Latitude Laptop

Tags: 16.04, dell, ssd

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 in my corporate PC which has Windows 7 pre installed. Laptop model is Dell Latitude E7440 and it has 500 GB SSD. I have McAfee drive encryption installed which asks for authentication pre boot. I freed up 30 GB space from my drive and tried to install Ubuntu in it. The Ubuntu installer takes all the input and drive size etc. But after everything when you click the last Next button it starts its operation, like creating partition, copying files etc. In this section I could see the create partition operation lasts for barely 1 sec, but all other installation everything happens and it shows installation done, restart now. But after restarting my PC can't boot to Ubuntu as there is no partition available. I checked in Windows Disk management, there also the space which I unallocated for Ubuntu shows as free space instead of the partitions. What could be wrong here? Does the McAfee drive encryption affect? Or the problem is because of SSD ? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. It looks like if you have McAfee drive encryption installed the partitions do not get created.